# Asynchronous logging with Apache Camel

Tags: asynchronous, logging, apache-camel, jbossfuse

I'm trying to implement an asynchronous logger with `Apache Camel`. I want to log the request and response payload while calling a 3rd party API. Currently, I'm doing this using `activemq` as follows:

```
....
<!-- Prepare request -->
<to uri="activemq:loggingQueue??disableReplyTo=true&amp;preserveMessageQos=true"/>
<recipientList>
  <simple>http4:api.example.com</simple>
</recipientList>
.......

<route>
  <from uri="activemq:loggingQueue"/>
  <!-- log payload -->
</route>
```

- Is there any better way to achieve this functionality?
- Can I integrated log4j2 asynchronous logging with camel? If it is possible, is there any tutorial demonstrating the same? I could n't see a any tutorial refering to `log4j2` asynchronous logging and camel together.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an `EventNotifier` to hook into Camel that has events before/after a message is sent to an endpoint. You can then use that to write to your logs: http://camel.apache.org/eventnotifier-to-log-details-about-all-sent-exchanges.html

And also log4j and other logging apis, often have various adapters to write the logs to files / over the network in a fast and asynchronous / batch fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, camel using sl4fj inside so you can tweak logback to perform async logging to fit your requirements. Here are some ideas: http://blog.takipi.com/how-to-instantly-improve-your-java-logging-with-7-logback-tweaks/